# Melting gold at room temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition

https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2018/11/181120125750.htm

I'm skeptical about how the researchers claim that the gold melted at room temperature.  Isn't what's really happening is that the electrical field is merely exciting the gold atoms, causing them to vibrate?  Isn't that the same as raising the kinetic energy of said atoms to above the melting point?

The way I see it is that the rest of the sample (and the surrounding environment) remain at "room temperature" while just the tip of the sample is actually heated to above the melting point.  Perhaps my skepticism is fueled by the wording of the article...

### Is there anything unusually exciting about these researchers' claims about "melting gold at room temperature"?

Comment: Abstract and images: https://journals.aps.org/prmaterials/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevMaterials.2.085006

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is exciting to see the feasibility of controlling the order/disorder of the surface with an electric field without increasing the temperature.

Reading the paper, the Physical Review Materials, not the Science Daily report, a few interesting things emerge clearly.
The researchers do not claim they have got  melting. They speak of *surface roughening*, which means the surface atoms are in a disordered space configuration. Still, this is a major accomplishment, since previous experiments were showing such an effect in presence of an electric field *and* high temperature.

Even more interesting, the mechanism suggested by the authors on the basis of an extended comparison of their experimental findings with some *ab-initio* computer simulations they did to better understand what was happening. 
Their explanation is that there is no local heating. It is the local accumulation of electronic charge which weakens the bonds favoring the possibility of bond-breaking and higher mobility of the atoms at room-temperature.

In summary, I think it is a very good piece of new physics, potentially opening interesting technological applications (controlling devices with electric fields is much more convenient than with temperature).